# Parsing the content of a cartouche using a "term parser"

Tags: isabelle

I want to implement a domain specific language (with its own parser) inside cartouches in Isabelle. For example, I would like the term `(MY ‹123›, 3)` to invoke my own parser for the substring `123`, but to parse the rest normally as terms.

Following `HOL/ex/Cartouche_Examples.thy`, I understand how to install my own parse translation for subterms of the form `MY ‹...›`, and how to get the content of the cartouche as either `string*Position.T` or as `Symbol_Pos.T list`.

I also understand how to use Isabelle's parser combinators to write a parser of type `term parser`.

But I cannot find out how to apply the parser to a string (or a `Symbol_Pos.T list`).

In other words, what I am still lacking is a function

```
fun parse_cartouche ctx (cartouche:string) (pos:Position.T) : term = ???
```

that applies my parser of type `term parser` to the string `cartouche` (and correctly reports parse errors to the top level).

**To clarify:**

- I want to make use of the existing infrastructure of Isabelle for tracking/reporting parsing locations. For example, if there is a parse error, I expect the code to be red in Isabelle/jEdit, and if inside my own language, I would call a parser like Args.parse_term, I would expect Isabelle/jEdit to color variable correct, and to get type information by control-hover.
- I prefer not to reimplement my own parsers for common things like int's etc., but can do so if I get at least the previous bullet point. (However, parsing a substring of my language as a term, I would have to some existing parsing function, since I cannot reimplement the Isabelle syntax on my own.

---

Below is my complete code so far (with a dummy implementation of `parse_cartouche`).

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin

ML {*
  (* In reality, this would of course be a much more complex parser. *)
  val my_parser : term parser = Parse.nat >> HOLogic.mk_nat

  (* This function should invoke my_parser to parse the content of cartouche.
     Parse errors should be properly reported (i.e., with red highlighting in
    jEdit etc. *)
  fun parse_cartouche ctx (cartouche:string) (pos:Position.T) : term = 
    (warning ("I should parse: " ^ cartouche ^ ". Returning arbitrary term instead"); @{term True})

  (* Modified from Cartouche_Examples.thy *)
  fun cartouche_tr (ctx:Proof.context) args =
      let fun err () = raise TERM ("cartouche_tr", args) in
        (case args of
          [(c as Const (@{syntax_const "_constrain"}, _)) $ Free (s, _) $ p] =>
            (case Term_Position.decode_position p of
              SOME (pos, _) => c $ (parse_cartouche ctx s pos) $ p
            | NONE => err ())
        | _ => err ())
      end;
*}

syntax "_my_syntax" :: "cartouche_position ⇒ 'a" ("MY_")
parse_translation ‹[(@{syntax_const "_my_syntax"}, cartouche_tr)]›

term "(MY ‹123›, 3)" (* Should parse as (123,3) *)

end
```

Comment: That's a pretty advanced questions. You probably have more success on the mailing list(isabelle-users@cl.cam.ac.uk) where the real isabelle gurus reside.

Comment: I've seen answers by a lot of the "gurus" (meaning the Isabelle core team) on SO. And I think asking on SO can help others who run into similar problems (because SO is easier to find than a mailing list discussion).

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a relatively rare use case, I'm not sure if a "canonical" solution for this has emerged yet. But I can at least give you two examples from my own code which should help illustrate the general approach.

### Evaluation of ML code in terms

[source](https://github.com/larsrh/purely-experimental/blob/master/Splice.thy)

The following parse translation, given a function `eval_term : string -> term`, extracts some ML source from a cartouche, evaluates it to a `term`, which is then used as the result of the parse translation.

```
fun term_translation ctxt args =
  let
    fun err () = raise TERM ("Splice.term_translation", args)
    fun input s pos =
      let
        val content = Symbol_Pos.cartouche_content (Symbol_Pos.explode (s, pos))
        val (text, range) = Symbol_Pos.implode_range (Symbol_Pos.range content) content
      in
        Input.source true text range
      end
  in
    case args of
      [(c as Const (@{syntax_const "_constrain"}, _)) $ Free (s, _) $ p] =>
        (case Term_Position.decode_position p of
          SOME (pos, _) => c $ eval_term (input s pos) ctxt $ p
        | NONE => err ())
    | _ => err ()
end
```

### Embedding XML

[source](https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle/blob/v0.7.0/modules/libisabelle/src/main/isabelle/protocol/Common.thy)

This one allows me to embed XML literals into terms which will then be interpreted as terms.

```
syntax "_cartouche_xml" :: "cartouche_position \<Rightarrow> 'a"  ("XML _")

parse_translation\<open>
let
  fun translation args =
    let
      fun err () = raise TERM ("Common._cartouche_xml", args)
      fun input s pos = Symbol_Pos.implode (Symbol_Pos.cartouche_content (Symbol_Pos.explode (s, pos)))
      val eval = Codec.the_decode Codec.term o XML.parse
    in
      case args of
        [(c as Const (@{syntax_const "_constrain"}, _)) $ Free (s, _) $ p] =>
          (case Term_Position.decode_position p of
            SOME (pos, _) => c $ eval (input s pos) $ p
          | NONE => err ())
      | _ => err ()
  end
in
  [(@{syntax_const "_cartouche_xml"}, K translation)]
end
\<close>
```

---

### Update

The following code should allow you to turn an `Input.source` into something digestible for the parser combinators, including full position information:

```
ML ‹
  val input = ‹term"3 + 4"›;
  (* a bit more complicated than just Input.pos_of because otherwise the position includes the
     outer cartouche brackets, which manifests as an off-by-one-error in the markup *)
  val pos = Input.source_explode input |> Symbol_Pos.range |> Position.range_position;
  val str = Input.source_content input;
  val toks = Token.explode Keyword.empty_keywords pos str;
  val parser = Args.$$$ "term" |-- Args.embedded_inner_syntax;
  parser toks |> fst |> Syntax.read_term @{context}
›
```

Comment: If I read your code correctly, then the content of the cartouche is ultimately transformed to a `string`, and then parsed. This has two problems for my case: I won't get good error messages (marking the parse error location in jEdit), and I will have to implement my own parser library (because the type `'a parser` in Isabelle does not run on string).

Comment: I was oversimplifying things a bit. The first example actually uses the `Input.source` type which stores position information. Using the parse translation still gives you full markup at the correct spots, as confirmed by Makarius (https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2015-June/msg00084.html). The `Input.source_explode` function gives you at least a list of symbols+positions which I think could work with parser combinators (haven't tried it though).

Comment: Ah. I see there is a subtlety here: Given `syms : Symbol_Pos.T list` you can translate it in two ways to a string (for subsequent parsing with, e.g., `Syntax.read_term`). Method 1: Use `Symbol_Pos.implode syms`. This will give you plain string, without position information. Method 2: Use `Syntax.implode_input (Input.source false (Symbol_Pos.implode syms) (Symbol_Pos.range syms))`. This gives you a string with position markup that can be used by `Syntax.read_term` and relatives.

Comment: _"The Input.source_explode function gives you at least a list of symbols+positions which I think could work with parser combinators"_
Not with the parser combinators of type `'a parser` (which covers a lot of interesting predefined parsers like `Parse.nat`). Because those work on `Token.T list` only, and I don't know how/whether one can convert one into the other. So I have to reimplement all those basic parsers as type `Symbol_Pos.T list -> 'a * Symbol_Pos.T list`. Well, that's doable, your input already helped a lot, I'll write a summary-answer once I've figured everything out.

Comment: I have a very vague idea of how cartouche contents can be transformed into `Token.T list`: `Token.explode Keyword.empty_keywords (Input.pos_of input) (Input.source_content input)`

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh I have updated my answer to include some code which hopefully does what you want.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do it. There are still minor problems, like that errors are reported as incomprehensible exceptions, and spaces are included in the token stream (you can't write <term "3+4">, only <term"3+4">, I think). But I found a solution to all these, I'll post it once I have polished it a bit. Thanks a lot for your help, it was very valuable in figuring out things.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @larsrh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619600/2646248) and own experimentation, I came up with the following answer.

- The parse translation gets the cartouche content as a string, together with a position. There can be converted into a `Symbol_Pos.T list` using `Symbol_Pos.cartouche_content o Symbol_Pos.explode`. (This is covered in the examples in Cartouche_Examples.thy, contributed with Isabelle.)
- The `Symbol_Pos.T list` can be converted into `Source.source` containing `Symbol_Pos.T`s using `Source.of_list`.
- The `Source.source` containing containing `Symbol_Pos.T`s can be converted into a  `Source.source` containing containing `Token.T`s using `Token.source'`.
- We remove whitespace tokens from this source using `Token.source_proper`.
- And the result is converted to a `Token.T list` using `Source.exhaust`.
- Finally, parsers of type `'a parser` can be applied to such a `Token.T list`. (Or, if we have an `'a context_parser`, then we need to additionally supply a context.)

Some additional work needs to be done: add an EOF to the `Token.T list` to allow parsers to detect the end of the input. Handle errors in the parser (to get nice error messages).

The code below is a complete commented working example (for Isabelle 2016-1), the source can also be found [here](https://github.com/dominique-unruh/IsaCrypt/blob/86a531b6a8d7f1cbebfd18ce65d9891845ed94f1/Scratch.thy).

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin

ML {*
(* test_parser is just a definition of a silly example parser. It parses text of the form "123 * ‹x+y›"
   where 123 is an arbitrary natural, and x+y a term. test_parser is of type term context_parser.
   The parser returns a term that is a list 123 copies of x+y.
   If you have constructed a "term parser" instead, you can either convert it using Scan.lift, 
   or modify the definition of parse_cartouche below slightly. 
 *)
fun sym_parser sym = Parse.sym_ident :-- (fn s => if s=sym then Scan.succeed () else Scan.fail) >> #1;
val test_parser = Scan.lift Parse.nat --| Scan.lift (sym_parser "*" || Parse.reserved "x") -- Args.term
  >> (fn (n,t) => replicate n t |> HOLogic.mk_list dummyT)

(* parse_cartouche: This function takes the cartouche that should be parsed (as a plain string
   without markup), together with its position. (All this information can be extracted using the 
   information available to a parse translation, see cartouch_tr below.) *)
fun parse_cartouche ctx (cartouche:string) (pos:Position.T) : term = 
  let 
    (* This extracts the content of the cartouche as a "Symbol_Pos.T list".
       One posibility to continue from here would be to write a parser that works
       on "Symbol_Pos.T list". However, most of the predefined parsers expect 
       "Token.T list" (a single token may consist of several symbols, e.g., 123 is one token). *)
    val content = Symbol_Pos.cartouche_content (Symbol_Pos.explode (cartouche, pos))
    (* Translate content into a "Token.T list". *)
    val toks = content |> Source.of_list (* Create a "Source.source" containing the symbols *)
      |> Token.source' true Keyword.empty_keywords (* Translate into a "Source.source" containing tokens.
             I don't know what the argument true does here. false also works, I think. *)
      |> Token.source_proper (* Remove things like whitespaces *)
      |> Source.exhaust (* Translate the source into a list of tokens *)
      |> (fn src => src @ [Token.eof]) (* Add an eof to the end of the token list, to enable Parse.eof below *)
    (* A conversion function that produces error messages. The ignored argument here
       contains the context and the list of remaining tokens, if needed for constructing
       the message. *)
    fun errmsg (_,SOME msg) = msg
      | errmsg (_,NONE) = fn _ => "Syntax error"
    (* Apply the parser "test_parser". We additionally combine it with Parse.eof to ensure that 
       the parser parses the whole text (till EOF). And we use Scan.!! to convert parsing failures 
       into parsing errors, and Scan.error to report parsing errors to the toplevel. *)
    val (term,_) = Scan.error (Scan.!! errmsg (test_parser --| Scan.lift Parse.eof)) (Context.Proof ctx,toks)
    (* If test_parser was of type "term parser" instead of "term context_parser", we would use instead:
    val (term,_) = Scan.error (Scan.!! errmsg (test_parser --| Parse.eof)) toks *)
  in term end

(* A parse translation that translates cartouches using test_parser. The code is very close to 
   the examples from Cartouche_Examples.thy. It takes a given cartouche-subterm, gets its 
   position, and calls parse_cartouche to do the translation to a term. *)
fun cartouche_tr (ctx:Proof.context) args =
    let fun err () = raise TERM ("cartouche_tr", args) in
      (case args of
        [(c as Const (@{syntax_const "_constrain"}, _)) $ Free (s, _) $ p] =>
          (case Term_Position.decode_position p of
            SOME (pos, _) => c $ (parse_cartouche ctx s pos) $ p
          | NONE => err ())
      | _ => err ())
    end;
*}

(* Define a syntax for calling our translation. In this case, the syntax is "MY ‹to-be-parsed›" *)
syntax "_my_syntax" :: "cartouche_position ⇒ 'a" ("MY_")
(* Binds our parse translation to that syntax. *)
parse_translation ‹[(@{syntax_const "_my_syntax"}, cartouche_tr)]›

term "(MY ‹3 * ‹b+c››, 2)" (* Should parse as ([b+c,b+c,b+c],2) *)
term "(MY ‹10 x ‹q››, 2)" (* Should parse as ([q, q, q, q, q, q, q, q, q, q], 2) *)
term "(MY ‹3 * ‹MY ‹3 * ‹b+c››››, 2)" (* Things can be nested! *)

end
```